# How to invalidate all tokens issued by the node-oidc-provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, node-oidc-provider

in our app we need to invalidate all tokens (access, refresh) issued by the node-oidc-provider. From our investigation there is no endpoint exposed by the node-oidc-provider.
As we have access directly to MongoDB where tokens are stored in collections `access_token` and `refresh_token` I would like to ask if it is save to e.g. set `expiresAt` field to `now()` and let MongoDB to remove those tokens because they are old. I'm not sure if it is enough or we have to expire something else stored in DB to keep data consistent.
Also I didn't find any suggested way in OAuth spec.
There is only some short advice from OKTA: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/listing-authorizations/revoking-access/